# mariadb won't restart after storage space induced crash

Tags: mysql, mariadb, rollback, crash

I have a large mariadb instance running (400 gb or so).

Due to running out of storage space it crashed.

I went ahead and resized my volume (I am using AWS), and went to restart the service `service mysql start`

It did not however start. `journalctl -xe` returns the error "2017-07-25 14:19:33 140139278653632 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for rollback of recovered transactionsto exit"

My assumption is that a transaction was executing, mariadb ran out of space and crashed. It is now trying to rollback that pending transaction and has yet to complete.

I am not particularly experienced with database administration, and I do not want to start messing around in a manner which could potentially corrupt my data.

I was wondering if anyone could share any insight on the appropriate way to discern if my assumption is correct, and how I can most appropriately resolve the situation?

Many thanks.